# Can get an warning or error for not including a header file directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I want to avoid this case:

**h1.hpp:**

```
#include <vector>
//some code
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "h1.hpp"
//#include <vector>  This include is commented.
int main(){
     std::vector<int> x; //works fine!
}
```

I want to get an error/warning that I am using `<vector>` while it is not directly included in MSVS.

Comment: Thats really not how the preprocessor works. If a header file is included anywhere it's included.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned <vector> is included in main.cpp because the pre-processor adds it from h1.hpp and so the compiler won't know the difference.... so it'll need to be done pre-processor time (or before)... not sure if that's possible....

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah I know that nothing wrong with it. But I want just the compiler to tell me that it was included by a deeper level not directly. it may be a static analysis tools job. However, I am asking if it could done by the compiler itself.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi but the compiler can't know this since the pre-processor sorts it out before the compiler runs...

Comment: @code_fodder I wrote it before I saw your comment. OK I see. So I should find some static analysis tool for this.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, ah ok, sorry you are replying to J's post : )   I think you can use `cl.exe /E` on a file to run the pre-processor and then take a look at the output the compiler gets (FYI). But yes, you will probably need to do your own thing here... not sure if you can do any clever pre-processor macros.. probably not, I can't think how.

Comment: @code_fodder I will try it.. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If `<vector>` is used as an implementation detail (i.e., function body), separate h1.hpp to h1_head.hpp (declarations) and h1_body.hpp (definitions). If you have structs / classes, you can hide the details by e.g. declaring a `detail` struct / class inside your class and only defining it in h1_body.hpp . Include h1_head.hpp before the code in main.cpp and h2_body.hpp *after* all the codes.

If any of the fuctions in h1.hpp take / return a vector or a related type, then maybe it's best to assume that main.cpp *will* have `<vector>` when including h1. An alternative to this is to say that h1 *requires* a vector class and thus not include `<vector>` in h1 but require it to be included in main.cpp (before h1) - this is, however very confusing as there's no programmatic way of documenting it (no, requiring a `typedef std::vector vector_t;` or a `#define H1VECTOR std::vector` is not documenting, it's false generalization).

Comment: hmm.... other then this answer makes little sense (or I am not clever enough to understand it), how are you going to test `If any of the fuctions in h1.hpp take / return a vector` during compile-time and generate warning? - that is what the OP was asking : )

Comment: Please elaborate which part doesn't make sense for you, so that I can describe / edit for you and for further readers. Yes, the answer is based on the precondition that user has control over h1.hpp . Note that the method in the first paragraph holds regardless of whether any of the functions take/return a vector. That's clearly not what OP is asking for, OP wants to know if `<vector>` was included due to h1.hpp or in main.cpp . I still hold that 1. my solution will work when `<vector>` is not on h1.hpp's interface and 2. if it's on the interface, then you have to live with h1.hpp including it.

Comment: But can you explain how this produces an error/warning if <vector> is used in main.cpp when (and only when) it is indirectly included.

Comment: h1_head.hpp:
void fn();

h1_body.hpp:
#include <vector>
void fn() { std::vector v; }

main.cpp:
#include "h1_head.hpp"

int main() { fn(); }

#include "h1_body.hpp"

Comment: It's a bit messy in comment section, but hope you can decypher it :). Note that OP didn't ask to have error when indirectly included but when it's *not* directly included. In my case, the include of <vector> itself will move after main().